# Method not found in node.js class

Tags: node.js

I have a class below which works fine.

```
class loginDBHandler {
    
    constructor(userName, password, connection) {
        this.connection = connection;
        this.userName = userName;
        this.password = password;
    }    
    
    authenticate(callback) {
        let objResult = {};
        let sql = "some sql"

        this.connection.query(sql, function (error, results, fields) {            
            var result = results[results.length - 1][0];
                
            var name = result.name;
            
            if(name === null) {
                objResult.Message = "Invalid Credentials";
            }
            else if(email === null) {
                objResult.Message = "Invalid email";
            }
            else {
                objResult.Message = "All good";
            }
            callback(objResult);
        });
    }
}

module.exports = loginDBHandler;
```

Then I thought to add a function below because there are many duplicate lines of this code `objResult.Message = "All good";`

```
prepareResultObject(message) {
    let objResult = {};
    objResult.Message = message;
    return objResult;
}
```

So the new class is like below.

```
class loginDBHandler {
        
    constructor(userName, password, connection) {
        this.connection = connection;
        this.userName = userName;
        this.password = password;
    }    
    
    prepareResultObject(message) {
        let objResult = {};
        objResult.Message = message;
        return objResult;
    }

    authenticate(callback) {
        let objResult = {}; let sql = "some sql"

        this.connection.query(sql, function (error, results, fields) {            
            var result = results[results.length - 1][0];
                
            var name = result.name; var email = result.email;
            
            if(name === null) {
                objResult = prepareResultObject("Invalid Credentials");
            }
            else if(email === null) {
                objResult = prepareResultObject("Invalid email");
            }
            else {
                objResult = prepareResultObject("All good");
            }
            callback(objResult);
        });
    }
}

module.exports = loginDBHandler;
```

Now, I got the compilation error - prepareResultObject is not found.

Am I missing anything?

Comment: `this. prepareResultObject ` ?

Comment: Type Error : `this.prepareResultObject` is not a function